# Using Promise inside SwitchMap operator

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, switchmap

```
source$.switchMap(x => promise(x))
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

source$.switchMap(x => from(promise(x)))
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

both the lines of code resolves the promise but can someone really point out what's the different in between these two lines of code ?

Comment: identical. but i suggest to be more explicit and add 'from'

Comment: Functionaly the two are identical because RxJS handles Observables and Promises the same way. Promise, from RxJS perspective is just an Observable that emits only one item.